# Make controller constructor value global codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Im trying to get the total unread accounts from the database, the value is assigned to `$data['head']`

I want to make the $data['head'] available globally so it will be automatically loaded into the template and displayed on the header.

What is the best way to do this?

Below is my controller

```
function __construct()
    {

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('process_model');
    $data['headbody']='includes/header';
    $data['head'] = $this->process_model->loadnew($this->session->userdata('id'));

    }


function invform()
    {
        $this->load->model('slave');
        $data['body']='slave-account';

        $data['questions'] = $this->slave->loadq($this->uri->segment(3));

        $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
    }
```

View

```
$this->load->view($head);

 $this->load->view($body);

 $this->load->view('includes/footer');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to make **$data** into a variable outside the function, using variable scope. Can be private or public. I made it private in this case.

Here's a quick revision:

```
private $data = array();

function __construct()
    {

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('process_model');
    $this->data['headbody']='includes/header';
    $this->data['head'] = $this->process_model->loadnew($this->session->userdata('id'));

    }


function invform()
    {
        $this->load->model('slave');
        $this->data['body']='slave-account';

        $this->data['questions'] = $this->slave->loadq($this->uri->segment(3));

        $this->load->view('includes/template',$this->data);
    }
```

Notice the **$this->data**, instead of **$data**. When we're accessing variables within the same class, but outside of the function, we use **$this**.